# Getting out Queue Name through Case Owner

Tags: formula, case, formula-field, ownership, queue

I have been asked to fill a custom field named "Group" with the Case's Owner Queue Name.
I have created a formula field like this

```
CASE(
        Owner:Queue.Id, 
        '00Gw0000002RvtS', "Gruppo A - Operations", 
        '00GZ0000001ls0m', "Gruppo B1 - TP_Service",
        "00Gw0000002RvtU", "Gruppo B2 - Infogroup",
        "00Gw0000002RvtW", "Gruppo C - Crediti",
        "00Gw0000002RvtX", "Gruppo D - Fatturazione",
        "00Gw0000002RvtY", "Gruppo E - Commerciale",
        "00Gw0000002RvtZ", "Gruppo F - Prospect",
        "00Gw0000002Rvta", "Gruppo G - TOP",
        "00Gw0000002Rvtb", "Gruppo H - PA",
        "00GZ0000001ltX8", "Gruppo I - Recard",
        "No_Value"
)
```

Now if the case owner is a queue then the result is ok, but if the owner is a User the formula doesn't work.
Is there any way to address this? I have tried to create a trigger, but I'm not a coding expert so I didn't succeed.
Any help?

Thanks in advance
Axl

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the Queue name, that's available to you in the formula.  Something like this should work

```
IF(
     Owner:Queue.Id <> null,
     Owner:Queue.QueueName,
     "No Value"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger createNewCase on Opportunity (before insert , before update) 
{
   //Create a map with UserId to respective values

   map<Id, String> mapUserIdToSTring = new map<Id, String>{'UserId1' => 'Gruppo A - Operations',
                                                            'UserId2' => 'Gruppo B1 - TP_Service',
                                                            'UserId3' => 'Gruppo B2 - Infogroup'
                                                            'UserId4' => 'Gruppo C - Crediti'};
    for(Opportunity objOpp:Trigger.New)
    {
      if(mapUserIdToSTring.containskey(objOpp.OwnerId))
      {
         system.debug(mapUserIdToSTring.get(objOpp.OwnerId)); //you will get Group Name based on User Id. Perform your logic here
      }
    }
}
```

Create trigger and add the values into map.
In above example `UserId1`, `UserId2` replace with actual User record id. Also remove the single quote.